# Replace a specific word followed by sometimes single digit number or other times two digit numbers

Tags: regex, matlab

Strings will always end with `'Row'` followed by a number.  For example,

```
desk_Row2.txt
desk_Row15.txt
```

If sorted, `desk_Row15.txt` will precede `desk_Row2.txt`.

If it's a single digit number, I want to put a leading `0` in front of it so that, when sorted, it will be:

```
desk_Row02.txt
desk_Row15.txt
```

I figured out a long way where I find `'Row'` with `findstr` and `'.'` and what's between them is a number.  Then I can figure out whether `str2double(that)` is greater than `9`.  Well, I think this can be done in a matter of one or two sentences.

More generally, I want to learn to create expressions so that I can do the above myself later on.  For example, I have no idea what `(^|\.)\s*.` means.

I was thinking to use `regexprep`, but I have no idea what the expression should be.

Comment: If you don't know what it means then [read the documentation that explains it](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html#btrug0n-1) and [utilize tools that explain the expressions and produce their outputs in real time](https://regex101.com/). If you're generating the filenames in another function I suggest utilizing [`sprintf`'s ability to explicitly write leading zeros](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html#btf_b35) rather than replacing after the fact.

Comment: Also, changing `'desk_Row2.txt'` to `'desk_Row02.txt'` is not going to make it switch places with `'apple_Row15.txt'` when the strings are sorted.

Comment: So, it is good that you follow the rule "If you do not understand, do not use it". However regex seems to be a good way to handle this problem in case you are not able to change the original names. However rather than asking here I think you will get a better outcome of this in case you read up on regex by yourself.

Comment: @excaza, I edited the post.  The post was a lot longer with more file names.  I missed changing apple to desk.  I went through the doc on regexp and sorry my comprehension level wasn't high enough.  I just asked that question if one could offer me a tip like a good tutorial URL or so.  I'll do more research.